# Can I put this rifle in my backpack?

Tags: dayz-2012

In *DayZ*, I've run into a problem. That problem is finding more weapons than I know what to do with.

Luckily, I also managed to find a nice 24-slot [backpack!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hMRq6.jpg) I know I can put bandages and various other supplies in said backpack, but that doesn't help me carry more weapons, as my arms are in short supply.

**Is there any way I can store excess weapons in my backpack?**

Comment: You can, but I don't actually own the game, only played it for a bit and watched many videos so I don't know how.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can.

Place your crosshairs over a weapon and open your gear. Then, open your backpack and you should be able to place that weapon into your backpack. If not, then equip the weapon and attempt to place it in your backpack that way.

A primary weapon will take up 10 slots, while a secondary weapon will take up to 5 slots.

Comment: Be aware that if there isn't room for the item, it will dissapear and be lost. So make sure you have the slots required

Comment: @Holger It doesn't always disappear. At least sometimes (if not always) it gets dropped on the ground, but not directly under your feet. It can be a few or maybe even over ten meters away. If there is grass around, that's a big problem, but on a flat surface free of grass you should be able to find it.

Answer (score 3):

You can put a weapon in your backpack in the same way you'd do any other item.  The difference is that sidearms take up 5 slots and primary weapons take 10 slots.  If you try to put a weapon in your backpack when you don't have the space, you might lose the item.